# Why does my IIS Express web application project throw an error in the output window when it attempts to load?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express, vs-web-application-project

A web application project which was converted to IIS Express and then checked into Team Foundation Server is kicking out an error when other developers try to load it. The error appears in the Visual Studio Output window and the associated web application project fails to load.

This is the error in the output window:

> The Web Application Project XXXX is configured to use IIS. The Web server 'http://XXXX' could not be found.

What is causing this issue and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I am unsure of the root cause of how a project that was converted to IIS Express would only save part of that setting, more than likely the issue is that your project file has its `UseIISExpress` node set to false. Open the project file up in a text editor (Visual Studio or otherwise) and change the nodes setting to true:

```
<UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
```

Once you've edited and saved the project file right click the unloaded project and select reload.

Comment: If the problem persists, check for the same setting in the .csproj.user file that sits alongside the .csproj.

Comment: That was our problem, the .csproj.user file. Thanks, @JT!